# Set tcp_fwmark_accept on a per-socket basis

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ebpf, bpf

My program is creating a TCP socket that is accepting traffic from multiple sources. Some of the traffic is marked with a fwmark, and other traffic isn't.

I want the reply packets from my socket to be marked with the fwmark of the SYN packet that established that connection. So exactly what `tcp_fwmark_accept` is doing. But I want to do so on a per-socket basis, not wholesale for the whole system.

BPF probes are an option, but the one I can think of, `BPF_SOCK_OPS`, [is not called before sending the SYN-ACK packet.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L6594). Since the SYN-ACK packet is not marked, it will not be delivered correctly and a connection cannot be established.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think code would help people understand this question better -- `tcp_fwmark_accept` is a sysctl option, and the question is of conceptual nature.